# Zoom in image when screen is larger bootstrap

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, slider, zooming

I am trying to make an image slider using bootstrap 3.3.7 with asp.net using visual studio 2010. So below is my code:

```css
.ImageSlide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  max-height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active ">
      <img class="ImageSlide" src="../Images/Image (1).jpg" alt="Image 2" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>
          Image 1</h3>
        <p>
          This is the first image.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item ">
      <img class="ImageSlide" src="../Images/Image (2).jpg" alt="Image 2" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>
          Image 2</h3>
        <p>
          This is the second image.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only"> Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Now I am trying to make images in each div of class item to be displayed in the hole div. And I want when the screen is large to zoom in the image like exactly what is done [here](http://wowslider.com/wordpress-gallery-plugin-grafito-seven-demo.html)  (Please click on the blue button "full width" and change the browser size to understand what I mean). Class ImageSlide is displaying the image in the hole item and is fixing the height exactly as I wanted. But in this case when screen is too large image is stretched. How can I make it zoomed in and displayed in the hole item at the same time?

Comment: You could use `background-image` with `background-size : cover`, here's a fiddle with an example https://jsfiddle.net/3nb5d13u/3/

Comment: Thank you sir @PascalGoldbach

Comment: You're welcome, if my comment helped you I'll also post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `background-image` with `background-size : cover` : https://jsfiddle.net/3nb5d13u/3/

Here's what I changed :

**CSS :**

```
.ImageSlide1
{
    background-image : url('yourbackground.jpg');
    background-size : cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div class="item active ">
   <div class="ImageSlide1" ></div>
   <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Image 1</h3>
      <p>This is the first image.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```